# nginx rewrite rules for front controller PHP application

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to convert  apache .htaccess rules into an nginx configuration.
The URLs that are requested by the browser look like:

- `thedomain.com/user/login`
- `thedomain.com/rates/create`
- etc

These URL's need to be rewritten to so that:

- PHP file that gets run is: `thedomain.com/index.php`
- The URI is converted to the corresponding `QUERY_STRING`'s:

  - `?url=user/login`
  - `?url=rates/create`

So in Apache this request - `thedomain.com/user/login`
would be internally rewritten to look like this:
`thedomain.com/index.php?url=user/login`

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The nginx config I have so far is

```
server {    
    listen 80;
    server_name thedomain.com;
    root /home/admin/thedomain.com/public;                                                                                     
    index index.php;

    location / { 
        try_files $uri /index.php?url=$uri;
    } 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;   
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
     } 
}
```

Unfortunately Nginx won't start with this configuration so I can't run nginx to generate any useful log/debugging information.
What do I need to do to get this config working?

Comment: First, figure out why nginx won't start, and fix that.

Comment: ok its because `unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` Im looking into it now, thanks

Comment: fixed that, now: `"fastcgi_param" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled line 13`  which is this line: `fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING url=$uri`

Comment: [If is evil!](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) As you can see in the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_param), the context for fastcgi_param is http, server, location. You cannot use it inside if.

Comment: @FlorinAsavoaie Where is an `if`? I don't see an `if` here?

Comment: It was before he edited the question :)

Comment: ah ok, I have replaced `if` with `try_files $uri /index.php?url=$uri;` - now the app is loading but returning 404's. the problem is that the app is expecting `/index.php?url=user/login` but the current config looks like it is probably sending - `/index.php?url=/user/login` which is probably easier to fix from within PHP .

Comment: sorted! used PHP's `ltrim()` function - and its working now